# Why Does EnableViewState=true mean a Gridview does not run Events on Postback?

Tags: asp.net, http, gridview

I have the following ASP.NET markup:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="dsTest"
                   runat="server"
                   SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM Test"
                   ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:DefaultConnection %>">
</asp:SqlDataSource>

<asp:GridView   ID="gvTest"
                runat="server"
                DataSourceID="dsTest"
                AutoGenerateColumns ="true"
                OnDataBound="gvTest_DataBound"
                OnDataBinding="gvTest_DataBinding"
                OnRowDataBound="gvTest_RowDataBound">
</asp:GridView>

<asp:Button ID="myButton" runat="server" Text="server" OnClick="myButton_Click" />
```

and the following code behind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Write("Page_Load<br />");
}

protected void gvTest_DataBinding(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Write("gvTest_DataBinding<br />");
}

protected void gvTest_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Write("gvTest_DataBound<br />");
}

protected void gvTest_RowDataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Write("gvTest_RowDataBound<br />");
}

protected void myButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Write("myButton_Click<br />");
}
```

When I load the page, I get the following output at the top of the screen:

```
Page_Load
gvTest_DataBinding
gvTest_RowDataBound
gvTest_RowDataBound
gvTest_RowDataBound
gvTest_RowDataBound
gvTest_RowDataBound
gvTest_DataBound
```

If I click the button, I get

```
Page_Load
myButton_Click
```

If I add `EnableViewState="false"` to my gridview markup, and do the same again, I get

```
Page_Load
gvTest_DataBinding
gvTest_RowDataBound
gvTest_RowDataBound
gvTest_RowDataBound
gvTest_RowDataBound
gvTest_RowDataBound
gvTest_DataBound
```

on the initial page load, and

```
Page_Load
myButton_Click
gvTest_DataBinding
gvTest_RowDataBound
gvTest_RowDataBound
gvTest_RowDataBound
gvTest_RowDataBound
gvTest_RowDataBound
gvTest_DataBound
```

after the button click.

Why does having the viewstate enabled mean that the gridview does not databind on postback?

Is it because the with the viewstate enabled, it has retained it data over the postback and therefore does not need to bind the data again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it because the with the viewstate enabled, it has retained it data
>   over the postback and therefore does not need to bind the data again?

Exactly. Without viewstate, each request is a fresh request with no knowledge of the request before it.

You can read this to learn more: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972976.aspx